# When listing Meta Serverfault SE questions -- Wrong author info is being displayed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just listed questions on the Meta SE site by pressing the Question button and notice that instead of seeing the avatar of the AUTHOR of the question.....it is showing the avatar of one of the authors of an answer.

Is this a bug?

This is not happening on the Serverfault main site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an obvious thing, but just in case: do you have the "Active" tab selected (circled) instead of "Newest" (arrow) ?[image: tabs]

Comment: Hmmmm....I did ... however I don't recall any of the SE things doing this before.

Comment: @mdpc The Active tab displays the user who is responsible for the most recent activity on the question, just like on the front page.